# How can I make VSCode handle textedit:// URIs?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, internals, lilypond

I'm trying to set VSCode to open on a specific line and column when clicking on an item inside of a PDF that contains the URI for that specific line and column. These PDFs have all those URIs with the textedit:// prefix. I still can’t figure out how to do this, but I kind of got to know that I need to use 「 export LYEDITOR="code --goto %(file)s:%(line)s:%(column)s" 」somewhere.

Please help me, I need this so much!

Comment: You should not set anything in VS Code. The question should be: "How can I set up Mac and its PDF viewer to open my favorite editor when I click on notation objects?". Unfortunately the answer is not easy. You can find lot of discussion on lilypond-user mailing list, but no easy solution. The path is twofold: 1. Make sure lilypond-invoke-editor script (distributed by lilypond.org) can be run from the command line without errors; 2. Let your PDF viewer run lilypond-invoke-editor when clicking on textedit URIs. The second step is the real challenge on Mac -while it's trivial in Linux and Windows

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this in [VSLilyPond](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lhl2617.VSLilyPond)

Basically, what is needed is a custom PDF viewer that can intercept these links, which I've written and bundled into that extension.